# WPF Prism reloading module using IModuleManager.LoadModule

Tags: wpf, prism

I need to display views in a Module.The Module Registers it's view using in `Initialize` method.
User will select module name from drop down list. First time it works using I`ModuleManager.LoadModule`(string ModuleName). If I want to re-display the same module again(in the same region after clearing the previously displayed module) `IModuleManager.LoadModule` is not going to work. I dont know the views and regions contained in that Module. I know just ModuleName and I need to display it's view.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions is very confusing. Can you provide more information? The IRegionManager is the component to register Views to your predefined Regions. The ModuleManager is only responsible to load an assembly if I got that right.

I don't think you can Load a Module multiple times, because the second time it is loaded already. The logic for displaying views should be regulated via Services within your Modul so inside your Module should be a Method that uses the IRegionManager to register a specific View to a Region.

I don't know whether you use Unity or MEF ( or another IOC ) but you can obtain the IRegionManager within your Module via the Container.

Maybe you should watch this Tutorial series [Prism Tutorial Series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTtTW-BmXJg). It seems to me you are missing some basic principles